# How do I turn off the fault tolerant heap on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, heap-memory, fault-tolerant-heap

This is the same question as on [turn off FTH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020418/how-do-i-turn-off-the-fault-tolerant-heap) but on Windows8 so maybe there's a different answer. I have tried ALL the suggestions there and it still won't go away. I'm trying to debug a 32 bit program on 64 bit Windows Pro 8. I've tried setting all the registry entries (and rebooting); these normally only exist in the 64 bit part but I added them to the 32 bit part as well. I've tried renaming the acxtrnal.dll file (both 32 & 64 bit versions). I've tried running the rundll32 suggestion given. None of these have stopped FTH running and destroying my program performance - an operation which took 5 seconds is now taking several minutes.

The only way I have found to get around it is to rename both the visual studio and my program executables - which I will have to do again when it next starts crashing (which it will - I'm doing development!!).

Any ideas?

Comment: you should visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020418/how-do-i-turn-off-the-fault-tolerant-heap

Answer (score 1):

To disable it for a single application

> Go to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and HKEY_CURRENT_USER versions of
>   Software\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers\your_application.exe and
>   delete the Fault­Tolerant­Heap entry.

or visit this link

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/itasupport/archive/2009/10/08/come-disabilitare-il-fault-tolerant-heap.aspx)